What is this tool shown to us?
The Boys, season 4, ep 3, during the make-out scene between Sage and the Deep, we are shown a sharp tool with its tip stained with blood.
What does this scene suggest?


The tool is known as an orbitoclast. It's a specific medical tool intended for the performance of "transorbital lobotomies".
Warning: Gory

 

The implication is that Sister Sage has performed a lobotomy on herself. The Deep finds her sitting watching TV, eating snack food and generally chilling out, all things she would consider to be worthless activities if she still had her full intelligence.
Not to worry though. Her fact file says that she has "moderate regeneration", so we can reasonably expect that this is temporary and something she does semi-regularly.

I thought it implied she killed the Deep love interest, that talking Octopus.

@YuZhang - I guess it could? But why would she use a tool that is specifically intended for performing lobotomies? And why, then, is she so interested in dumb people pursuits like TV, snack food and meaningless sex?

Is it confirmed in the show that this is the tool? From the still provided by the OP it just looked like a pair of scissors, albeit with long blades, with perspective making it look more long and pointed.

@dbmag9 - There's a better view a few seconds earlier; https://i.sstatic.net/Mi0nS7pB.png. It sure as hell looks like an orbitoclast to me, and the use fits the context (e.g. she's acting like someone who just got a lobotomy).
